# How to Cluster Image Colors Using K Means Clustering in CIE a*b Domain?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, clustering, unsupervised-learning, k-means

I am working on building detection from aerial images using Image Processing in MATLAB.

I am doing an image segmentation based on the local homogeneity of image. I want to apply [K Means Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) in [CIE LAB Color Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) with some clusters on the anisotropic diffused image for color quantization and generate the image for further processing.
My RGB image is of 877 X 454 dimension.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`makecform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html) to create a color transfer structure.
You should use `srgb2lab` to create a structure which will convert you to LAB.
To apply the color transformation use [`applycform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/applycform.html).
Then, as a result you'll have an image in the LAB domain.

Then use [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) to cluster the image colors on the AB channels.

Good Luck...